# Active Directory multi-site "trust proxy"

Tags: active-directory, proxy

We have a multi-site domain with several sites in a hub and spoke-design. From the hub site, we have established a one-way trust to another domain though a VPN tunnel.

Now, when someone from the external domain tries to authenticate, our domain controllers will return a referral to the other domain. However, the tunnel is only open for the domain controllers in the hub site.

Can we somehow put use a proxy in this situation? I've been reading up on AD LDS, which comes up in searches on the topic, but it is not apparent to me how/if it would work. It seems OpenLDAP also has some proxy functionality, but I'd rather not introduce it unless it is the only option. Any other options?

Answer (score 0):

No, you must allow the referrals in the firewall. Neither ADLDS not openLDAP will authenticate users.  The simplest solution is to put a DC from the other domain in the hub site.